# Какова этимология и значение слова « колошматить»?

Tags: этимология, лексика, значение-слов

«Данный глагол в значении "бить, колотить" известен не только в русском, но и в других восточнославянских языках, **однако до сих пор происхождение его не установлено**, а этимологические словари вообще его не фиксируют». Этимологические исследования, 1981, И.П.Детлева  (Москва).

**КОЛОШМАТИТЬ**,  кого (что). Разг. Бить, колотить; наносить поражение противнику. К. друг друга. К. со всей силы.

**Из словарь Даля,  2012.** КОЛОШМАТИТЬ / кого, бить, колотить, комшить.| пск. врать вздор без разбору. Колошматник муж. драчун, забияка.

Но "бить" и "колотить"  могут быть синонимами. И что означает «комшить»?

**Текст для примера**

Над головой что-то промелькнуло, и он успел увидеть черное покрывало, которое падало на него сверху.

–  **Колошмякай его!** – запищал кто-то, и крепкая нога врезала по ребрам.

Со всех сторон посыпались пинки и удары. Они были сильные, но терпимые. Его пинали, кусали, царапали, прыгали по спине в ботинках. Примерно через минуту основательно потоптанному М. удалось выпутать катар и длинным ножом распороть покрывало. Последний пинок пришелся по локтю, после чего что-то маленькое и многочисленное юркнуло во тьму (Современная фантастика).

Comment: Комшить, вероятно, какая-то очень древняя ошибка. [А вот здесь](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&biw=1138&bih=506&tbm=bks&ei=-Hf4X8OaHeKgrgTc4KqwCg&q=%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%2C+%D0%9A%D0%9E%D0%9B%D0%9E%D0%A8%D0%9C%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%98%D0%A2%D0%AC+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&oq=%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%2C+%D0%9A%D0%9E%D0%9B%D0%9E%D0%A8%D0%9C%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%98%D0%A2%D0%AC+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&gs_l=psy-ab.3...6921.9318.0.9990.4.4.0.0.0.0.230.691.0j3j1.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.WDwQely373M) кошмить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашёл это слово в добротном этимологическом словаре украинского языка. Там сказано, что в украинском это слово заимствовано из русского, в котором оно "является, может быть, экспрессивным образованием, результатом контаминации слов *колотить* и *кошмить* ("валять, сбивать в кошму")". (Кошма — это войлочный ковёр из овечьей или верблюжьей шерсти.)

В качестве источника информации указано следующее: Шанский ЭСРЯ, II 8, 215. (Этот выпуск вышел в 1982 г.)

Нашёл и этот источник, который немного отличается в части "кошмить" (украинский словарь существенно более поздний и по опыту я доверяю ему чуть больше, но такое расхождение можно было бы и прояснить):

> **Колошматить** (бить). Очевидно, собственнорусское КрЭС 971, 206).
> По
> ССРЛЯ впервые отмечается в Опыте 1852 г.  Происхождение неясно. Может
> быть, является результатом контаминации двух слов: *колотить* (см.) и
> несохранившегося *шматить* — тж (ср. диал. *шматовать* «рвать, резать на
> части»), образованного на базе заимствования из польск. яз. (через
> посредство укр. и бел. яз.) *шмат* (польск. *czmat* — тж) «кусок, ломоть»,
> ср. диал. *шмотье* «лохмотья» (Даль 1880, IV, 640; КрЭС 1971, 206). Ср.
> просторечн. *шмотки* «одежда, личные вещи». См. *колотить*,  *шмотки*.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, две очень интересные версии, и обе вполне возможны. Мне более знакомо слово "шматок" – кусок, он и в словаре есть: ШМАТ, Разг.-сниж. Кусок чего-л. отрезанного, отломанного (обычно о еде). Шмат сала, мяса. Отрезать от хлеба большой шмат.

Comment: коло = по кругу и шматить = нарезать, откуда прямо получаем: колошматить = нарезать круги. шутка.